# Was there paint under the stain I stripped off?

Tags: staining, refinishing

I'm striping an old headboard for a bead frame with the intention of re-staining it.  As I am working I noticed that the consistency and color of the stuff I'm stripping from the large flat surfaces is different from that of the the stuff coming off of the curved embellishments and details.  Also the wood looks much different there too.  I'm pretty sure there is some kind of facing of nicer looking wood on the large surfaces.

So my question is: I this paint under the stain?  If it's not paint what is it?  When I go to stain it again how should I go about getting a nice looking result as there was before?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a stain under a film finish, but without more detail or some photos it's pretty hard to tell.

Comment: Also, the carved details are likely made from a wood that's easier to carve, then applied to the larger piece.

Comment: The "facing" you're referring to is probably a "veneer"...a very thin sheet of primary wood glued to a less-expensive substrate.

Comment: As a rule there would never be paint under stain. There might be paint under 'stain' though, since the word stain has been corrupted in recent years to include coloured overcoats such as 'gel stain'.

Comment: Re. refinishing, remember that wood doesn't need to be stained. You only stain if you want to change its colour. So if you're happy with the natural colour of the wood then you can go straight to your topcoat, which will probably be a varnish or a 'Danish oil' type product.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback.  I'm really not sure what to make of it. 
 Hopefully this project turns out ok.  There is defiantly a vaneer on the wood.  I'm worried that the non-vaneer'd areas will not look the same as the vaneer'd areas once the stain is applied.  Is it possible that it was just painted to match the stain or something like that?